# How to find out the sum of all the rows corresponding to the dates if the values are given as cumulative?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have the following dataframe as input

[image: Input]

Now I want the sum of all the values of the column 'Confirmed' belonging to the corresponding date. But since the values are given as cumulative sum so I want the output as

[image: Output]

Here for date `01-04-2020` the sum for `Bulgaria and China`(both provinces) would be  200+300+400
 but for `02-04-2020` it would be `(250-200)+(350-300)+(450-400)` which would be `150` since these are the cumulative values and the previous values of `200,300` and `400` are also being added in them which have to be subtracted.Please let me know how can we do it in pandas.

Comment: Can't see your dataframes. Can you please post the dataframes as code.

Comment: Can you also show what you've tried?

Comment: Sure . This is what I tried and it worked now. I created a new column in the dataframe with the name 'difference'  df['difference'] = abs(df['Confirmed']- df['Confirmed'].shift(-1))   and then df=df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'difference':'sum'}).reset_index()                                                Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this, is to use groupBy and shift.

1. GroupBy date into grouped_by_date_df: so you would have in this dataframe:

   - 01-04-2020: 900
   - 02-04-2020 : 1050
2. subtract grouped_by_date_df.shift(1) from grouped_by_date_df:

   result = grouped_by_date_df - grouped_by_date_df.shift(1).fillna(0)

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. However I did it a bit differently. This is what I tried and it worked now. I created a new column in the dataframe with the name 'difference'                                                       
df['difference'] = abs(df['Confirmed']- df['Confirmed'].shift(-1))   and then df=df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'difference':'sum'}).reset_index()                                                Thanks for the help though!